# Dynamic Image in Android Studio TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am building a simple app using Android Studio and Kotlin.

The app shows that for each month the results are either `0` or `1` and is used in a TableLayout format.

[image]

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="1dip"
       android:text="January" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/JanYear1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="1dip"
        android:text="0" />


</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="1dip"
        android:text="@string/februrary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FebYear1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="1dip"
        android:text="1" />


</TableRow>
```

Rather than showing the results being `0` or `1`, I would like it to be an image:

[image] or

[image]

and the result to be dynamic according to some code?

Comment: Show your activity or fragment

Answer (score 0):

**Here's my proposition**

> XML

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#BBFFAA"
            android:text="MONTH"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#AACCBB"
            android:text="YEAR"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

> JAVA

```
TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);


String[][] months = {{"janvier", "0"}, {"February", "1"}, {"March", "0"}, {"April", "1"},
        {"May", "1"}, {"June", "1"}, {"July", "1"}, {"August", "1"},
        {"September", "1"}, {"October", "1"}, {"November", "1"}, {"December", "1"}};


for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {

    TextView month = new TextView(this);
    TextView year = new TextView(this);

    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    layoutParams.weight = 1;

    month.setText(months[i][0]);
    month.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tableRow.addView(month);
    //
    if ((months[i][1].equals("1"))) {

        year.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ok);
        //
        tableRow.addView(year);
    } else if (months[i][1].equals("0")) {

        year.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no);
        tableRow.addView(year);

    }

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

Here's the result :

[image]

Comment: here's how to accept an answer : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks! I'm struggling now to find the line "ok" (in  year.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ok)? i.e. where is "ok" defined please? Cheers

Comment: Ok  is a picture that you have mentioned on your example, i'm just calling it "OK" where the  value of years is 1  and "NO"  for 0

Comment: you can download this project here : https://github.com/AbderazakAmiar/tableLayout

Comment: here's how to clone project from github in android studio =>  https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-clone-a-github-project-on-android-studio/

Comment: That is great! Have now got it working :-) Really appreciate that. CHEERS

Comment: Ok great, So, you can accept the answer, here's how to do it https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work